# GCP Machine Images size

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am looking to utilize GCP Machine Image for backups.  I have a PostgresSQL application and need to keep multiple disks in sync.

So when reading the GDocs on Machine Image (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images) there is a section named Differential Backups.  The MI page under Compute Engine shows the number of Images created and little else about the image itself.  I need to find the size of these differential backups and a method to view across multiple projects.

Thanks

Comment: In fact, you are looking for knowing the size of your snapshots, isn't it?

Comment: No, I'm not taking a snapshot of individual disks.  I'm taking a machine image of the entire VM (boot disk and attached disk).    I am looking for the size of the machine image

Comment: Ok, it's still a beta product, I think it's too young to have these information